# How can i load asset bundle which don't know the name of asset?

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, assetbundle

I want to load and instantiate asset from my asset bundle, but in unity 5.+ i can do it with code like this:
Note: my assetbundle have one asset inside itself, like:

```
AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle;
public string path;

void Start()
{
    LoadAssetBundle(path);
}

void LoadAssetBundle(string bundleUrl)
{
    myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(bundleUrl);
    Debug.Log(myLoadedAssetBundle == null ? "Faild To Load" : "Succesfully Loaded!");
    Debug.Log(myLoadedAssetBundle.mainAsset.name);

    Instantiate(myLoadedAssetBundle.mainAsset);

}
```

}

actually even i use

```
Debug.Log(myLoadedAssetBundle.mainAsset.name);
```

to log name of mainasset of my assetbundle!

but in unity after 5+ , they say mainasset is obsolete.

my questions is:

1- **How can i load asset bundle which don't know the name of asset?**

2- **How Instantiate or assign sprite which loaded of assetbundle ?**

Answer (score 4):

According to the [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html) documentation, there is now the ability to call [GetAllAssetNames()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.GetAllAssetNames.html) to return a list of all asset names in a bundle as a string array. You can load the assets from the bundle via a for loop with those asset names.

Alternatively, if you are guaranteeing to only have 1 asset per bundle you can simply grab the string at index 0 (not recommended).

Additionally, you can load the assets without knowing the names by using [LoadAllAssets()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAllAssets.html) which returns an array of the specific type (in your case you would specify Sprite).

Comment: thanks man, but in the past i try :myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset(myLoadedAssetBundle.GetAllAssetNames()[0])
but , didn't work!

Comment: Have you confirmed that GetAllAssetNames()[0] containsa a non-null value? Consider using LoadAllAssets() and checking to see that you receive back an array of gameObjects. @Rooz

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: (Note - You will need to know your directory path to each asset, here, I'll make some stuff up as an example)

```
private List<GameObject> assetBundle = new List<GameObject>();
private GameObject asset1 = Resources.Load("Weapon1") as GameObject;
private GameObject asset2 = Resources.Load("Weapon2") as GameObject;  
private GameObject asset3 = Resources.Load("Weapon3") as GameObject; 

private void Start()
{
assetBundle.Add(asset1);
assetBundle.Add(asset2);
assetBundle.Add(asset3);
}
```

Now you can access them from the list by element whenever you wish. However, I'm not 100% certain that Resources.Load() will work for what you're trying to do. I am about 65% - 70% though so I answered. Hope it helps!

Comment: `Resources.Load` has been deprecated in favor of [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html).

Comment: I was unaware of this. I appreciate the information! @Draco18s

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution,

```
IEnumerator LoadBundleFromDir(string bundleUrl)
{
    //which type of asset i want load
    GameObject model;
    AssetBundleCreateRequest bundleRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(bundleUrl);
    yield return bundleRequest;
    AssetBundle localeAssetBundle = bundleRequest.assetBundle;

    Object[] allBundles = localeAssetBundle.LoadAllAssets();
    foreach (Object item in allBundles)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(GameObject))
        {
            AssetBundleRequest assetRequest = localeAssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>(item.name);
            yield return assetRequest;
            model = assetRequest.asset as GameObject;
            localeAssetBundle.Unload(false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```